# How do you unlock the football helmet?

Tags: halo-4

I am almost up to level of the football helmet. I'm trying my best at flood and spartan ops. I just dont know what to do to unlock it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you are talking about the [Ricochet helmet](http://halo.wikia.com/wiki/MJOLNIR_Powered_Assault_Armor/Ricochet) which is only available by purchasing the [Bullseye DLC Pack](http://halo.wikia.com/wiki/Bullseye_Pack) also included in the Championships DLC bundle.

Answer (score 0):

I got it when I bought the Champions Pack (DLC).

I also got Master Chief's first set of armor dots richochet weapon skins and hero stances.

Comment: @Riley - seems to answer the question by saying buy the champions pack.

Comment: @camelCase You're right, my bad.